# Lable pointer in piechart using c#

Tags: c#

Why does the pointer so thick in my webpage chart, but not in my design page.
i have a pie chart designed with lables outside the pie using lable pointer.
In my design page the pointers are thin as desired. But in webpage it looks thick, not sure why it gets reflects like that.
Please help to resolve.

:[my design page pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7ycG.png)

[:my webpage chart looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5UY0.png)

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart5"  runat="server" Width="600px" height="331px"  Palette="None" 
          PaletteCustomColors="Teal; 255, 128, 0; 192, 192, 0; Maroon; Purple">
<BorderSkin BorderWidth="5" />
<Series>
<%-- <asp:Series Name="Summary group" ChartType="Pie" ChartArea="ChartArea5"  IsValueShownAsLabel="true" >
    </asp:Series>--%>
   <asp:Series Name="Total" ChartType="Pie" ChartArea="ChartArea5"  IsValueShownAsLabel="true" 
   customproperties="PieLabelStyle=Outside, PieLineColor=Black" Label='"#PERCENT"' MarkerSize="1">
    </asp:Series>

</Series>
<ChartAreas>

<asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea5" IsSameFontSizeForAllAxes="true" AlignmentOrientation="Horizontal"> 
<%--<area3dstyle enable3d="True" inclination="0"></area3dstyle>--%>
  </asp:ChartArea>


</ChartAreas>

 <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Name="Legend5" Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="Right">
        </asp:Legend>

    </Legends>
</asp:Chart>
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly! - You may need to set the border width..

Comment: It's ASP, Thanks. Itried using border width but no change.:(

Comment: Thanks TaW, it worked.

Comment: You may want to post the working code and an image as an answer, so others can see what to do..